# Unable to call a method within a schedule job

Tags: python, python-3.x, schedule

I have a class that looks like this:

```
class Account(object):
    """A simple bank account"""

    def __init__(self, balance=0.0):
        """
        Return an account object with a starting balance of *balance*.
        """
        self.balance = balance

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        """
        Return the balance remaining after withdrawing *amount* dollars.
        """
        self.balance -= amount
        return self.balance

    def deposit(self, amount):
        """
        Return the amount remaining after depositing *amount* dollars.
        """
        self.balance += amount
        return self.balance
```

I'll initialize it in `xyz`:

```
xyz = Account(balance=6000)
xyz.balance
> 6000
```

I also have a dumb printing function:

```
def thing():
    print("I am doing a thing...")
```

When I try to call the `deposit` method in my `schedule` flow:

```
import schedule

# this works
# schedule.every(5).seconds.do(thing)

# this doesn't work
schedule.every(5).seconds.do(xyz.deposit(2300))

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
```

I get the following error:

> TypeError: the first argument must be callable

Any ideas? Is it even possible to call methods within a schedule flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not familiar with `schedule`, but it seems like `do()` [wants](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#schedule.Job.do) a callable, i.e. a method.  You're giving it the return value of `xyz.deposit(2300)`, rather than the method `xyz.deposit` and the argument `2300`. Try this:

```
schedule.every(5).seconds.do(xyz.deposit, 2300)
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! I haven't, however, been able to get this to work for methods without input variables... it thinks that I'm trying to access an attribute. Thoughts?

Comment: I tried a minimal example and it worked for me.  Post exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Forgot `self` in my method. It works otherwise. Thanks for confirming.